# How to make a ajax call in angularjs with paramaters

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to fetch user location in angularjs via ajax call but I am getting syntax error

```js
app.controller('locationController', function($scope, $window) {

  $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    console.log(position);
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;

    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.lat = lat;
      $scope.long = long;
    });
  });

  var city = function() {

    http.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
      lat ","
      long "&sensor=true").success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
});
```

the error that I am getting is syntax error on tokens, delete this token

Comment: well, first you have to start by having proper string concatenation. `"foo" somevar "foobar"` is not how you concatenate strings in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least three problems:

1. It appears that you are not concatenating strings properly in your `http.get` call.
2. `lat` and `long` are out of scope of the `city` function as far as I can tell.  You maybe meant to use `$scope.lat` and `$scope.long`?
3. `http` is a service and you are not injecting it.

   ```
   app.controller('locationController', function($scope, $window, $http) {    
      $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
         console.log(position);
         var lat = position.coords.latitude;
         var long = position.coords.longitude;

         $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.lat = lat;
            $scope.long = long;
        });
     });

     var city = function() {

       $http.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
          + $scope.lat + ","
          + $scope.long + "&sensor=true").success(function(response) {
             console.log(response);
       });
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

try this, $http needs to be added.. angularjs supports 2 methods for ajax.  one is strictly function call (4 action types, get, post, update, delete) or add a config object such as the $.ajax.

```
app.controller('locationController', function($scope, $window, $http) {  // updated
    var city = function() {

    $http.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="  // updated
      lat ","
      long "&sensor=true").success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: certainly one of the problems, but there's far more wrong with the code.

Comment: i didn't read his code thoroughly.. but bottomline, $http is required!